# Oracle SQL - Find special non numeric characters in field

Tags: sql, string, oracle, select

How can I identify the datas that have anything else than a number in them in a where clause ?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```
SELECT *
  FROM <table>
 WHERE REGEXP_LIKE(<column>, '[^[:digit:]]');
```

Hope it helps...

Comment: Note that REGEXP_LIKE is only available in Oracle 10 or higher

Comment: @aiGuru, I'd hope the OP was using a database that was released within the past decade! If they're still on 9i or lower they are so far out of support as to make the question irrelevent.

Answer (score 5):

You can also use the TRANSLATE function to do this, as follows:

```
SELECT *
  FROM A_TABLE a
  WHERE LENGTH(TRANSLATE(a.FIELD, 'x0123456789', 'x')) IS NOT NULL
```

The expression `LENGTH(TRANSLATE(a.FIELD, 'x0123456789', 'x'))` will return NULL if the field contains only numeric characters.  If non-numeric characters are present it will return the number of non-numeric characters.

Share and enjoy.

Comment: This worked pretty well for me; I had an issue where a field could be a number, null, or have text, and I needed to count anything with any text like it was null. I had to have a couple checks in addition to this one, but it was very helpful for cases where I had both numerical and non-numerical characters in the string.

Answer (score 3):

Try this

```
SELECT *
FROM table
WHERE regexp_like(column_name,'[^0-9]+');`
```

This will pick all those rows which have non numeric characters in the column.

For details check this [page](http://www.oraclebin.com/2012/12/how-to-check-non-numeric-value-in.html).

Answer (score 2):

OR this one

```
select * from <YOUR_TABLE>
where LENGTH(REPLACE(TRANSLATE(<YOUR_TABLE.your_column_name>,
                               ’0123456789′, ‘@@@@@@@@@@’), ‘@’, NULL)) > 0;
```

Answer (score 2):

While not perfect (doesn't account for characters like '#', '@', etc.) a quick and dirty solution is:

```
SELECT * FROM <YOUR_TABLE>
WHERE UPPER(<YOUR_TABLE.your_column_name>) = LOWER(<YOUR_TABLE.your_column_name>)
```

Answer (score 0):

you could use Translate and filter out the values which have non numeric characters and then order on the columns.

```
select * from (
    select case  WHEN trn > 0 then NULL  else fld1 end New_column, fld1,trn FROM 
        (
        SELECT '123ab' fld1, LENGTH(TRIM(TRANSLATE('123ab', ' +-.0123456789',' '))) trn FROM dual UNION ALL
        SELECT 'a123b', LENGTH(TRIM(TRANSLATE('a123b', ' +-.0123456789',' '))) FROM dual UNION ALL
        SELECT '1256.54', LENGTH(TRIM(TRANSLATE('1256.54', ' +-.0123456789',' '))) FROM dual UNION ALL
        SELECT '4567899', LENGTH(TRIM(TRANSLATE('4567899', ' +-.0123456789',' '))) FROM dual UNION ALL
        SELECT '-56',LENGTH(TRIM(TRANSLATE ('-56', ' +-.0123456789',' '))) FROM dual
        )
)order by new_column
```